# Is there a German dialect where “w” is pronounced as it is in US English?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

When I hear Americans pronounce words and names of German origin, they almost always pronounce *w* as if it were in an American English word.

This got me wondering: I’m sure most or almost all of these instances is the result of American anglicisation, but is there any German dialect where it is pronounced that way? Could there be any German with a Germanic surname who might have moved to the US already pronouncing the *w* in their name that way?

Comment: A simple and thorough answer would be "no"

Comment: @Beta Then you should write an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: As a foreigner, I noticed this too (and I'm always very aware of such things). Germans may *think* they pronounce it as an English "v", but in reality, they usually don't. They pronounce a "w" as in English or Dutch. I guess I'll get a lot of flak for this, but it is something I observed many many times.

Comment: I knew someone who pronounced a more or less American English "r" by default but I believe his "w" was still pretty German. I think he was from a city in Saxony with its own local dialect that differed greatly from standard Saxon. Taking Wrzlprmft's answer into account it is well possible that this originated in the strong Sorbic influence in some parts of Saxony.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

"W" in German is always pronounced like "V" in English. The "W" (exactly) as pronounced in English doesn't exist in any German dialect. (See Ralf's and Thorsten's answers which get very close.)

> Could there be any German with a Germanic surname who might have moved to the US already pronouncing the 'w' in their name that way?

Yes, there could.

Comment: Waaaaas? I pronounce the *w* in *was* or *Wattenscheidt* as in English/Dutch/etc. So does everyone around me. On the contrary, I do notice that some Germans pronounce the English name *Victor" as *Wiktor* (English/Dutch/whatever W sound, not V sound) . Germans often seem to have problems pronouncing a proper *v* like in *vase* or as in my name). Also reminds me that in German, a *V* is usually pronounced as an *F*; think of the *Commodore Vic 20* home computer, which was renamed *VC 20* in Germany. <g>

Comment: You seem to misunderstand - the German phoneme for "W" is like the English one for "V" - *Vuttenshite* for an English speaker. The closest you get to the English "W" is "U" in German.

Comment: I don't misunderstand. People from Wattenscheid say (English W) "Wahtenshite", not "Vahtenshite". So the official pronunciation may be "Vahtenshite" but people simply don't pronounce it that way. I just listened to several conversations on TV and people generally use the "W" phoneme, not the "V" one. That is why it sounds terribly weird if Germans try to pronounce the English names "Victor" or "Vincent" and say "Wictor" or "Winsent", with an audible "W" phoneme, so not in the least as described here. Many may think they are pronouncing it as "V", but they don't. Often, a "W" is used. [cont'd]

Comment: With "V" I mean the phoneme as used in English, Dutch, French (e.g. as in vase, veterinarian, etc.), and with "W" I mean the phoneme as used in most languages (e.g. as in World Wide Web). I don't know the official "phoneme language signs" for these.

Comment: When you talk about phonems, please don't use latin letters. Use the IPA-Symbols for phonems instead: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen

Comment: @RudyVelthuis. You are talking about "English, Dutch, French", but Dutch /ʋ/ is quite different from English or French /w/.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Das muss ein komisches Uattenschait sein, von dem du da sprichst. In meinem Wattenscheid sprechen die Leute ihre Stadt ganz normal aus, zumindest war es früher so, ich hatte da mal gearbeitet. Vielleicht hat sich das ja geändert, die vielen amerikanischen Filme im Fernsehen und so... Manchmal sprechen ältere Leute sehr nachlässig, aber nur sehr alte Leute, dann sparen Sie eine halbe Millijoule, wenn sie die Unterlippe nicht bis an die oberen Schneidezähne bringen. Hab's grade mal selbst probiert, hört sich ein bisschen an wie Froschquaken - also nein, wirklich nicht!

Comment: Nicht Uattenschait, sondern Wattenscheid. Und das  "W"-Phonem ist die normale Aussprache. Habe heute alle Leute beobachtet, und einige gefragt. Sie sprechen es mit einem ("englischen") "W" aus (wie "world wide web"), nicht als "V" (wie "vase"). Und auch nicht als "U" wie in Eduard, sondern als "W" wie in Edward. Ich wohne und arbeite im Ruhrgebiet. Man kann vielleicht meinen, dass das anders ausgeprchen wird, aber ich habe heute genau darauf geachtet. Wird es nicht. Die Schneidezähne werden nicht bemüht.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ich bin nicht sicher, dass ich dich richtig verstehe mit dem 'englischen W', und das andere, was du erzählst, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Hier mal ein 'schönes' Lied aus der fraglichen Zone, da kann sich ja dann jeder selbst 'en Höreindruck verschaffen, wie 'Wattenscheid' ausgesprochen wird:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaFlq7j_ubY
ca. ab 0:30.

Comment: @fdb: Not that much. The French one is more a "ou" sound, perhaps. And Hubert: I don't intend to let my train of thoughts to be interrupted by a tedious search for some IPA symbol. I don't know IPA, I have no means of typing those symbols, so I let them be. I think I can make myself pretty clear without.

Comment: @Ralf: in that song, I only hear the "W" (world wide web) sound, no "V" (the one formed with the teeth on the lower lip) sound. Thanks for confirming what I said. But again, because some Germans **think** they pronounce *W* as a "V", they tend to pronounce English words or names like "Victor" or "Vincent" as "Wiktor" and "Winsent", thus pronouncing them wrongly.

Comment: I guess I'm hearing impaired - that's a mostly normal, German "W" for me. The Ruhr version is minutely different (tighter lips) from the W I'm used to but definitely not an English "W" as in WWW.

Answer (score 5):

> Could there be any German with a Germanic surname who might have moved to the US already pronouncing the w in their name that way?

Not exactly Germanic, but through the [Polish immigration to Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poles_in_Germany), there are some surnames to which the following happened (and which I witnessed in reality):

- The origin is a Polish surname, which contains a *[ł](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81#Polish),* e.g. *Domagała.*
  This was commonly pronounced /w/ like the English *w* (e.g., in *were*).
- Upon immigration to Germany, *ł* was transcribed as a *w,* e.g., the surname turned into *Domagawa.*
- For some reason (keeping the heritage, genealogical emphasis), some members of the family keep or return to pronouncing the *w* as /w/ instead of /v/.

Now, all you need is these people migrating once more to the US.

Answer (score 2):

I know only two dialects where this is the case in *some* regions: Rheinländisch and Bayerisch.

One example for the former would be this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOFrToWlu-4

Answer (score 1):

Die Antwort von @Zac67 ist richtig, allerdings:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB1ymE4Acys

ca. 0:21

Ist nicht wirklich so wie im Amerikanischen, aber auch nicht so wie im Standarddeutschen, sondern immerhin bilabial. Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie typisch das ist.

Außerdem gibt's im Bayrischen ein 'ui' für das standarddeutsche 'il', z.B. 'Fuim' für 'Film', oder im Satz 'Do san vui zvui Preissen do.' Das ist aber eine andere Geschichte, es hat nur eine entfernte Ähnlichkeit mit engl. 'we' und das 'u' steht hier auch nicht für ein 'w' ...

Comment: Ja, der Laut ist auf jeden Fall sehr ähnlich, aber nicht ganz dasselbe.

Answer (score 0):

/u/ followed by another vowel, as in "Linguistik" or the given name "Eduard", sounds very similar to the English /w/.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask if there is a German dialect that pronounces the letter *w* in the English way? I can't see any *w* in *»Eduard«*

Comment: Edward mag Lingwistik, denn er ist Linwistiker. There you go! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although this not German, there are Polish Surnames like:

Steve Wozniak(Woz) is pronounced with the American "W" instead of a "V" sound like in German or Polish.

There are no places where I have seen/heard the "W" Pronounced like an American "W", I guess an American Immigrant community could work if you want to settle with that

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

Btw: Imho, the closest you can get in German to the American pronounciation of 'W' - as in "Wood" ... is 'W' - as in "Wut" ...